# \title flowing off page in \documentclass = tutfe-book

Tags: titles, tufte, text

I suspect this is something in the inner workings of the tufte book class, so I'm not sure how readily it can be diagnosed or solved.

The following code:

```
\documentclass[]{tufte-book}
\geometry{a5paper}
\geometry{margin = 1 in}
\author{author name}
\title{nice long title goes here}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{test Chapter Title}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis vel nunc hendrerit odio fermentum consequat. Curabitur blandit semper metus eget dapibus. Fusce consectetur ac mi sit amet iaculis. Morbi ac egestas metus.

\end{document}
```

Produces the following pdf:

http://puu.sh/p0Mpx/5346cbd8dd.pdf

The title is clearly flowing off the page, if anyone is wary of clicking strange links.

I've played around with the geometry class, but am unable to get it to work. I could resort to the book class, but rather like the styling of tutfe-book. If anyone has any suggestions, it'd be most appreciated.

Comment: I can confirm the same results on my rig. Also i had similar issues when trying to convert my tufte-book thesis from A4 to A5. I gave up.

Comment: One solution is to use `\\` to insert line breaks within the title where you'd like them. The line breaks should automatically be removed from the running heads and other places.

Comment: @Buschmann Did the `a5paper` option not work for you?

Comment: @godbyk Well, it did turn the paper to A5 but the titlepage was similar to OP's example and the floats was everywhere from misaligned to missing. But mind you, this was a thesis with lots of floats. I wasnt exactly surprised.

Comment: `\geometry{a5paper,margin=1.5in,marginparwidth=1in,marginparsep=1em}` You have to amend the marginparwidth and maybe the *sep* as well. Depending on your actual title, you might get overfull boxes nevertheless, because the title is set ridicoulusly big.

Comment: @godbyk I  tried adding "\\" to the title and that works to some extent, with two issues.

1) It throws a "Token not allowed in a PDF string (unicode)" warning. I've googled around, and I don't see an easy solution. That said, it's only a warning, not an error. 

2) More importantly, it renders the title as such: http://puu.sh/p1onN/625217d971.jpg - notice the indentation on the second line. You can get clever with a negative \hspace and essentially fix it, so it's not *really* a problem, but is there a better / cleaner / simpler way to do it? Any tips appreciated.

Comment: It turns out that Tufte-LaTeX doesn't provide an A5 layout—only A4 and B5. My mistake! I've added a possible layout and explanation of the underlying problem in an answer below.

Comment: @DanielHunter You can safely ignore the `Token not allowed in a PDF string (unicode)` warnings if it's complaining about something you don't need to see printed. It just means that hyperref couldn't convert something to an ASCII or Unicode character for use in, e.g., the title property of the PDF metadata.

Answer (score 1):

While you've adjusted the page size and left margin, you haven't adjusted any of the other text block dimensions or margins. If you add `\geometry{showframe}` to the preamble, you'll see the various dimensions outlined. The text blocks extend beyond the right edge of the paper. The problem that you're noticing isn't an issue with line-breaking, but rather that the text block is too wide for the page.

Since Tufte-LaTeX doesn't provide its own A5 layout, you'll have to define your own. Here's one example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

% must be set first, so the
% \paperheight and \paperwidth
% dimensions are properly set
% before doing all the math later
\geometry{a5paper}

% now we can do some math!
\geometry{
  % vertical dimensions
  includeheadfoot,
  top=\paperheight/18,
  headsep=\baselineskip,
  textheight=15\paperheight/18,
  heightrounded,
  bottom=\paperheight/9,
  % horizontal dimensions
  left=\paperwidth/12,
  textwidth=7\paperwidth/12,
  marginparsep=\paperwidth/24,
  marginparwidth=5\paperwidth/24,
}

% to see the fruits of our labor
\geometry{showframe}

\author{author name}
\title{nice long title goes here}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\chapter{test Chapter Title}

A margin note just so we can see how it looks.
\marginnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac,
adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur
dictum gravida mauris. Nam arcu
libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna. Donec vehicula augue
eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi
tristique senectus et netus et
malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus
rhoncus sem.}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Feel free to adjust the ratios to accommodate the content of your book. For example, if you have a lot of material in the margins, you may want to make the `marginparwidth` wider and the `textwidth` narrower.

Generally speaking, the smaller the paper size, the more difficult LaTeX will find it to nicely typeset the pages. There are a large number of other parameters that may need to be tweaked as well (e.g., more relaxed line-breaking, adjusted float parameters).